# Require on address(this).transfer(msg.value) throws error

Tags: upgrade, solidity, contract

need help understanding why `require` is throwing an error and stopping my contract from compiling. The function is meant to allow the proxy owner to upgrade the current version of the proxy contract and call the new implementation to initialize whatever is needed through a low-level call.

```
function upgradeToAndCall(address implementation, bytes memory data) public payable
    onlyProxyOwner
    {
      upgradeTo(implementation);
      require(address(this).transfer(msg.value)(data),'');
  }
```

Two errors I am getting

```
No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.

Type is not callable
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I started learning Solidity so I know very little but aren't you trying to call a function on a non-function?

`address(this).transfer(msg.value)` is not a function but yet you are passing a parameter to it `(data)`. 

I'm just trying to troubleshoot with you. What do you think?

Comment: No, it is a function. address(this) returns the current contract type; address.

Comment: I get it, `address(this)` returns an `address` then transfer(msg.vaule) is chained to this 'address'. but what does the whole thing returns? it certainly doesn't return a function. a function will return a value, lets say transfer(msg.value) returns a boolean, then what you are doing is true(data). for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.There is no need of using transfer function in require, by default it throws error if transfer doesn't happen.
You could use .send() function if you want to keep inside require().

2.By default eth sent through payable function will be stored in the contract itself, so no need of using address(this).transfer(msg.value). Instead you can use and other address to transfer ether.

3.And passing (data) to transfer() function is incorrect.

Comment: The code is from OpenZeppelin with some modifications based on linter error message. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-labs/blob/master/upgradeability_using_unstructured_storage/contracts/OwnedUpgradeabilityProxy.sol Original code is  require(address(this).call.value(msg.value)(data),'') but it throws error.

Comment: There is difference between .transfer and .call(), in case of openZepplin's code a  fallback function called by passing value and data
```
contract Test {
    
    bytes public checkBytes;
    function () payable external {
        checkBytes = msg.data;
    }
    
    
    function pay(bytes memory value1) payable public {
        address(this).call.value(msg.value)(value1);
    }
}
```
Once check this example for clear understanding of openZepplin's code. Data passed to the function will be sent to fallback function